# Simplifying logarithmic expression

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

### Background

An integral is solved, and I get the following expression:

$$I = \frac12 \ln \left| \frac{u-1}{u+1} \right| - \frac u{u^2 - 1} + C$$

Teacher's solution states that from there:

> If we set $u = \sqrt{x / (x+1)}$ then we get $I = \ln \left| \sqrt{|x+1|} - \sqrt{|x|}\right| \pm \sqrt{x(x+1)} + C$

And challenges the student to find their way there, but I can't.

### Progress

I've split the log of a fraction into a difference of logarithms, and filled in the suggested substitution, but it stops there. I.e., I have

$$I = \frac12 \ln\left|\sqrt{\frac{x}{x-1}}-1\right| - \frac12 \ln\left|\sqrt{\frac{x}{x-1}}+1\right| - \frac{\sqrt{\frac{x}{x-1}}}{\frac{x}{x-1}-1} + C $$

### Question

How is that transition reached?

Comment: Is it supposed to be $\ln|\sqrt{|x+1|}-\sqrt{|x|}|\pm\sqrt{x(x+1)}$?

Comment: @KamalSaleh - Yes! Edited, thanks.

Comment: What result have you obtained?

Comment: @Gonçalo - I split the log(fraction) into a difference of logarithms, and simply filled in the substitution, but it stops there. So nothing substantial. Edited it into the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way you can try to solve it.

Firstly, we need to identify the domain of the integrand to ensure we preserve it when finding the antiderivative. We can do that by observing the given substitution $\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}$, which has this domain $x\in(-\infty;-1)\cup[0;+\infty)$. Now let's subtitute $u$ and simplify some fractions:
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}-1}{\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}+1}\right|-\frac{\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}}{\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}\right)^2-1}+C$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}-1}{\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}+1}\right|-\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}\cdot\frac{x+1}{x-x-1}+C$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}-1}{\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}+1}\right|+\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}\cdot(x+1)+C$$
Next, we rationalize the denominator and simplify:
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}-1}{\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}+1}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}-1}{\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}-1}\right|+\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}\cdot(x+1)+C$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}-1\right)^2}{\frac{x}{x+1}-1}\right|+\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}\cdot(x+1)+C$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}-1\right)^2\cdot(x+1)\right|+\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}\cdot(x+1)+C$$
Now, this is where our domain findings kick in. If we want to separate our radical expressions to have separate radicals for numerator, denominator, we need to add absolute values inside each separate radical to preserve the domain, otherwise they won't exist for negative values of $x$. We do it like so and simplify:
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\left(\frac{\sqrt{|x|}}{\sqrt{|x+1|}}-1\right)^2\cdot(x+1)\right|+\frac{\sqrt{|x|}}{\sqrt{|x+1|}}\cdot(x+1)+C$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{\left(\sqrt{|x|}-\sqrt{|x+1|}\right)^2}{|x+1|}\cdot(x+1)\right|+\frac{\sqrt{|x|}}{\sqrt{|x+1|}}\cdot(x+1)+C$$
We use absolute value properties to simplify further:
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{\left|\left(\sqrt{|x|}-\sqrt{|x+1|}\right)^2\right|}{||x+1||}\cdot|x+1|\right)+\frac{\sqrt{|x|}}{\sqrt{|x+1|}}\cdot(x+1)+C$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{\left(\sqrt{|x|}-\sqrt{|x+1|}\right)^2}{|x+1|}\cdot|x+1|\right)+\frac{\sqrt{|x|}}{\sqrt{|x+1|}}\cdot(x+1)+C$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\sqrt{|x|}-\sqrt{|x+1|}\right)^2+\frac{\sqrt{|x|}}{\sqrt{|x+1|}}\cdot(x+1)+C$$
We can rewrite $x+1=\pm\left(\sqrt{|x+1|}\right)^2$ so they have the same domain and range. Notice the result is $+$ when $x>-1$, $-$ when $x<-1$, and $0$ when $x=-1$ so sign doesn't matter. We use this and logarithm properties to simplify further:
$$\ln\left|\sqrt{|x|}-\sqrt{|x+1|}\right|+\frac{\sqrt{|x|}}{\sqrt{|x+1|}}\cdot\pm\left(\sqrt{|x+1|}\right)^2+C$$
$$\ln\left|\sqrt{|x|}-\sqrt{|x+1|}\right|\pm\sqrt{|x|}\cdot\sqrt{|x+1|}+C$$
$$\ln\left|\sqrt{|x|}-\sqrt{|x+1|}\right|\pm\sqrt{|x(x+1)|}+C$$
We can remove the absolute value in $\sqrt{|x(x+1)|}$, because in our domain $x\in(-\infty;-1)\cup[0;+\infty)$ and for this domain the expression inside absolute value is positive anyway, so no need for absolute value. We use absolte value properties in the logarithm's argument and this leads to the desired result:
$$\ln\left|\sqrt{|x+1|}-\sqrt{|x|}\right|\pm\sqrt{x(x+1)}+C$$
I hope this helps! :)

Comment: This is very thorough, thank you! I'm currently working on digesting it. I have a question though. When we blanket introduce absolute value signs around all the sqrt arguments, I understand that we're now allowing negative domains on them, and persisting our original domain. But how do we know that the negative values of the domain BEHAVE the same as the positive values? Obviously we're now forcing them to, but aren't we inherently changing the behaviour?

Comment: @Alec Good question! We aren't changing the behavior of the negative values by adding absolute values into radicals. In the original substitution $\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+1}}$ the reason why some negative values of $x$ are allowed is because negative signs cancel out during division (since the allowed negative values turn the numerator and denominator negative), and once that happens we are diving two positive quantities under a radical. (I'm running out of characters, so please see the follow-up comment for continuation)

Comment: @Alec (continuation of the previous comment) When we split our radicals into separate radicals and add absolute values exactly the same thing happens: we end up with two positive quantities (exactly the same as we would have in the original substitution, once the negative signs cancel out) being divided by each other, except they have separate radicals now, which makes no difference, since  $\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}=\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}$. So, the behavior is preserved for negative values once we add absolute values into radicals' arguments.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

$$\dfrac{u-1}{u+1}=\dfrac{\sqrt{x/(x+1)}-1}{\sqrt{x/(x+1)}+1}\times\color{red}{\dfrac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x+1}}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+1}}=-(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x+1})^2$$

$$\dfrac{u}{u^2-1}=\dfrac{\sqrt{x/(x+1)}}{x/(x+1)-1}\times\color{red}{\dfrac{x+1}{x+1}}=\dfrac{\text{sign(x+1)}\times\sqrt{(x+1)^2}\times \sqrt{x/(x+1)}}{x-(x+1)}$$
$$=-\text{sign(x+1)}\times\sqrt{x(x+1)}$$

$\text{sign(x+1)}$ refers to [Sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).